# Google Admin, can't enable Gsuite applications for certain users

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I'd like to know if anyone else experienced this issue before (and if so, how did you solve it):

We've added 28 users to our google admin panel, then we've enabled Gsuite apllications for all of the users, and everyone of those 28 accounts works fine, however then we've added 2 more accounts (**we've re-enabled Gsuite for everyone**), but none of those 2 users have access to the Gsuite, even after 24 hours (**As the admin panel advices to wait 24 hours after re-enabling the Gsuite**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182426?hl=en). Make sure that you have Enabled API access in the Admin console. You must be signed in as a [super administrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986#super_admin) for this task.

Also, another reason why some of your users don't have access to Gsuite is they are tagged as [Suspended Users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33312).

> **What happens to a suspended user’s account and data?**
>   *G Suite access—G Suite services, such as Google Drive files, Gmail, and so on are  unavailable to the user.*

Here are [possible reasons](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1110339?hl=en):

- Automatically suspended by the system for being at risk.
- Temporarily restricted from some or all actions in their Gmail account for exceeding some [account limits](https://support.google.com/a/topic/28609).
- Automatically suspended from Gmail for potential [spam abuse](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6389191).

If this is the issue, you may check the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1110339?hl=en) on how to fix it. However, you can’t restore an account that was suspended for abuse or for breaching the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/terms/user_terms.html). See the page for your corresponding recovery options.